# Rails form doesn't submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that stays on the same page after clicking the submit button.

Here is the form

```
<%= form_for @department do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :department %>
   <%= f.text_field :department_name:%>
       
   <%= f.submit "Create a Department" %>
<% end %>
```

the controller

```
def create
    @department = current_user.departments.build(department_params)

    if @department.save
     redirect_to :action => :index
     else
     render :new    
    end
  end
```

and this is what i have at the logs

```
Started GET "/departments/new?authenticity_token=1wZ%2BskqaBHda9GgEGElHx3uLa3wNii7%2BN1Z3r6WbYMAo9GpQJxrkdIi2ckpd0SDV64AFlvbZ7B9z4b%2FEwQ%2BEMw%3D%3D&department%5Bname%5D=Choir&commit=Create+a+Department" for ::1 at 2021-02-25 14:15:48 +0000
Processing by DepartmentsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"1wZ+skqaBHda9GgEGElHx3uLa3wNii7+N1Z3r6WbYMAo9GpQJxrkdIi2ckpd0SDV64AFlvbZ7B9z4b/EwQ+EMw==", "department"=>{"name"=>"Choir"}, "commit"=>"Create a Department"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering departments/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered departments/_form.html.erb
```

what am i missing please?

Comment: Your form is being sent as a `GET` request, not sure why though, it should to a POST by default using the form_for helper, you can force it adding the `method: :post` option to it. What's in `@department`?

Comment: i added method: :post and it still not working. it was working initially till i added tailwind

Comment: please add the controller action which renders that form.

Comment: its there please

Answer (score 0):

Okay so iwas basically having a form tag wrapping around the form_for, that was making it a GET request. After removing it, it works